# How to create a widgets on your own home screen in android?

Tags: android, homescreen

How to create widgets on our own home application. So that user can get all the user installed widget on press of a button and delete it on press of back button

Comment: What version of android?

Comment: Its version 2.3 (Gingerbread ).

Comment: I have my own home application, Which is using surface view to play video. Now I am trying to put some widgets on it for look and feel. (AS it works in default launcher2 application) I am able to add widgets on the surface view but not able to delete all the widgets.